# Divide values in one column by values in another one index back in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, datatable

I have a table that looks like this:

| taken | total |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | 30.02 |
| NaN | 68.03 |
| 174.0 | 18.67 |
| NaN | 44.50 |
| 134.0 | 68.33 |

I want divide all the numbers in the taken column by the number in the total column one index back. The resulting column would look like:

| taken | total | kpi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | 30.02 | NaN |
| NaN | 68.03 | NaN |
| 174.0 | 18.67 | 2.55 |
| NaN | 44.50 | NaN |
| 134.0 | 68.33 | 3.01 |

I got the KPI values by dividing 174.0/68.03 and 134.0/44.50, respectively. How can I achieve this with a SELECT statement in MySQL?

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return for you? You may use window functions for this if you are using MySQL 8.0.

Comment: I'm using version 8.0.32, so it should work with window functions, how would I implement it?

Comment: One more thing: What is the order of rows based on? You show only two columns, but neither of these can be used to determine order. Do you have a timestamp or a numeric primary key in this table?

Comment: I have a timestamp, a user ID, and an ORDER_LINE_NUMBER column as well, they should be ordered by user ID, then timestamp, then order_line_number. They are already ordered correctly in my starting table.

Comment: Rows have no innate order, if you want some particular order you need to specify it.  Your starting table having the correct order is not good enough; changing your query or version or even data changes can cause a different order of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT taken, total, 
  IF(taken = 'NaN', 'NaN', ROUND(taken / lag_total, 2)) AS kpi
FROM (
    SELECT taken, total,
      LAG(total) OVER (ORDER BY user_id, timestamp, order_line_number) AS lag_total
    FROM a_table_that_looks_like_this
) AS t;
```